# Awk Calc Avg Rows Below Certain Line

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble calculating an average of specific numbers in column BELOW a specific text identifier using awk.  I have two columns of data and I'm trying to start the average keying on a common identifier that repeats, which is 01/1991.  So, awk should calc the average of all lines beginning with 01/1991, which repeats, using the next 21 lines with total count of rows for average = 22 for the total number of years 1991-2012.  The desired output is an average of each TextID/Name entry for all the January's (01) for each year 1991 - 2012 show below:

TextID/Name 1
Avg: 50.34
TextID/Name 2
Avg: 45.67
TextID/Name 3
Avg: 39.97
...

sample data:

```
TextID/Name 1
01/1991, 57.67
01/1992, 56.43
01/1993, 49.41
..
01/2012, 39.88
TextID/Name 2
01/1991, 45.66
01/1992, 34.77
01/1993, 56.21
..
01/2012, 42.11
TextID/Name 3
01/1991, 32.22
01/1992, 23.71
01/1993, 29.55
..
01/2012, 35.10
continues with the same data for TextID/Name 4
```

I'm getting an answer using this code shown below but the average is starting to calculate BEFORE the specific identifier line and not on and below that line (01/1991).

```
awk '$1="01/1991" {sum+=$2} (NR%22==0){avg=sum/22;print"Average: "avg;sum=0;next}' myfile
```

Thanks and explanations of the solution is greatly appreciated!  I have edited the original answer with more description - thank you again.

Comment: I think you want `awk '$1=="....`. `$1="xxx"` assigns to field 1. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your response but that calculates all zeros for the average when I do that.

Comment: The other thing about `$1="01/1991" is that because it is an assignment, it will always be true, and all records will process the `sum+=$2`. It might help if you flesh out your question a little more. Currently we have no idea why you have picked 22 (I can guess), AND more importantly we have no idea of your desired output and no real picture of your existing output. OR you can just add some print statements on all of your variables to debug the problem yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your file, the first field is "01/1991," with a comma at the end, not "01/1991". Also, NR%22==0 will look at line numbers divisible by 22, not 22 lines after the point it thinks you care about.

You can do something like this instead:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { l=-1; }
  $1 == "01/1991," { 
    l=22; 
    s=0; 
  }  

  l > 0 { s+=$2; l--; }
  l == 0 { print s/22; l--; }'
```

It has a counter l that it sets to the number of lines to count, then it sums up that number of lines.

You may want to consider simply summing all lines from one 01/1991 to the next though, which might be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use Perl instead of Awk, you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$start = 0;
$have_started = 0;
$count = 0;
$sum = 0;

while (<>) {
  $line = $_;

  # Grab the value after the date and comma
  if ($line = /\d+\/\d+,\s+([\d\.]+)/) {
    $val = $+;
  }

  # Start summing values after 01/1991
  if (/01\/1991,\s+([\d\.]+)/) {
    $have_started = 1;
    $val = $+;
  }

  # If we have started counting,
  if ($have_started) {
    $count++;
    $sum += $+;
  }
}

print "Average of all values = " . $sum/$count;
```

Run it like so:

```
$ cat your-text-file.txt | above-perl-script.pl
```